# Attaching washing machine hose to two closely-positioned valves

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine

In my new apartment, I have the following washing machine valves installed:

[image]

And this is how my hose attachment looks like:

[image]

**The problem is** that the hose cannot be attached to the right valve, because the two valves are very tightly positioned relatively to each other. This makes the hose impossible to fit in.

How can I get around this? Is there any metal, right-angle extension I could buy and extend the right valve with? Or maybe an extension to be used on the hose itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the upper valve is installed with a threaded or compression fitting, you should be able to rotate it counterclockwise a bit to create clearance. If you provide more detail we can give more specific instructions.

Otherwise, take your washer hose (or some good photos and measurements) to your local hardware store and purchase a short flexible hose extension.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'm not a plumber, so it's hard for me to determine the type of the fitting installed, but I will check the valve at home and let you know if I need more help.

Comment: I'm not a plumber, either. :)

Comment: You were totally correct - I was able to rotate the valve with a bit of force. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Just keep an eye on it in the off chance you've loosened the seal too much. It's possible there's some thread compound or Teflon tape that would need reapplication if you detect any leaking.

Comment: Yep, it leaks a little. Kind of annoying. I would like to fix it but also don't want to break it. There's this flat metal part, like a cover, here: i.imgur.com/fAi65FU.jpg. Do you think I can take it out somehow and reapply the tape?